# How to see if an answer is flagged?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I came across [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184910/100734) answer which is of very poor quality and is not actually correct but because it's one year old I think it might have already been flagged.

How can I find out if that answer has been flagged?

Comment: Even if it's already been flagged, the flag hasn't been processed, so does it really matter?

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Didn't they update the low-quality-que since then?

Comment: How's that answer VLQ? As for being incorrect, that's _not_ a reason to flag it.

Comment: We can see only pending delete votes on answer, with 20k reputation.

Comment: Anyway, I agree with @Yannis, the answer might not be great, but it's an honest attempt to reply, and does not deserve to be deleted. You can downvote, you can add a comment - but that's about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see if someone else flagged a question or what its status is. Some flagged posts end up in a review queue so you should be able to find it there, although there is no easy way to do so.

If it was you who flagged the post, you will see the flag type grayed out when flagging again:

> [image]

Another way to find it back: you can find the post back in your flag history (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/). Again, no easy way to go through it. If you have flagged a lot, you have to go though every page to see if you flagged it before and if it was handled or not.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot see if a post has been flagged in the past. And you don't need to.

If you feel there's something wrong with a post, flag it. Crap slip through the cracks all the time, it's not unthinkable that a crap post has escaped detection for some time.

Also, a site's rules evolve over time. What was acceptable a year ago may not be acceptable today.

Comment: PS. I don't think the answer in question should be flagged.